# How to call multiple git commands using one .gitconfig alias

Tags: bash, git

Here are my current aliases in .gitconfig, and they work great. However, I'd like to have a single alias that can do all three.

**Example of what I'd like at terminal:**

```
git x my_commit_message
```

**Psuedo-code of .gitconfig:**

```
[alias]
         x = add -A <then do> commit -m <use variable from command line> push
```

I have push set to default = current, so push alone works.

```
[push]
    default = current
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine add, commit and push, you'll need a bash function.   Git add and commit can be combined with `git -am "msg"`, but the push can only be done as an additional command.  So, just define a bash function like this:

```sh
gacp() {
  git add -A &&
  git commit -m "${1?'Missing commit message'}" &&
  git push
}
```

This works by doing the `git add -A` first, and *if* it succeeds, then the command `git commit -m` is executed, with the required message, and *if* that succeeds, then the `git push` is executed.

It's important to make the latter commands depend on *successful* execution of the previous commands in order to avoid downstream messes.  In other words, you don't really want to `commit` changes unless the `add` succeeded, and you don't really want to push your most recent commits unless the `commit` succeeded.

You use it like this:

```sh
gacp "Latest changes"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use shell function to be able to execute multiple commands inside a git alias.

1. First, start with `!` so Git will run it as a shell command.
2. Write your function, like: `f() { git add -A && git commit -m "$1" && git push }`.
3. Execute your function just after its declaration.

You should write something like:

```
[alias]
        x = "!f() { git add -A && git commit -m \"$1\" && git push } f"
```

Note that:

- `$1` will be replaced by your variable from command line,
- `&&` will execute the next command only if the previous one has succeed.